# HttpRequestValidationexception on Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m getting an HttpRequestValidationexception with this error message:

> “A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client”.

But I have AllowHtml on the property that I’m getting the error.
The problem is that later in my code I’m getting the following property to know in witch format I will show my view `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("format")`. And on this “Param Getter” I’m getting the error.

Let’s say my code is similar to the following:

```
public class House
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateTopic(House h)
{
 //business code
 if(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("format"))
 {
    Return view;
 }
 }
```

How can I solve this? I already try with the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute on the controller action method. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.config in the `<system.web>` section:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Then include the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute back on your action.

Scott Hansleman explains this feature [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but I putting in danger my application with this? What does requestValidationMode="2.0" ? It will still valid the rest of the inputs?

Comment: Yes it will, it just enables you to turn off input validation for specified actions by using the `[ValidateInput]` decorator.  I've added a detailed article about this feature to the original answer.